# Retrieving statistical information when 2 rows are involved

Tags: sql, pandas

I need to get some information from a data set (csv) which I have boiled down to the following simple table,

```
Date_Time               Id     passed 
2013-06-23 20:13:10     112       A
2013-06-23 20:58:11     112       B
2013-06-23 21:01:10     118       A
2013-06-23 21:03:31     118       A
2013-06-23 21:05:49     118       A
2013-06-23 23:05:08     118       B
2013-06-24 08:10:03     118       B
```

The first two records show the simple case, after a check-in (A) we see 0:45:01 later 
a check-out (B).

But one can also have more check-ins in row (records 3,4,5) and the check-out following
later. Normally, there would be for every check-in a corresponding check-out. 
Unfortunately, the data is not perfect and there are sometimes records missing. (In the 
example there are only two check-outs for three check-ins)

I would like to get some statistical values of the times between check-in and check-out, 
perhaps on month basis or by weekday and so on. But I also do have to find a way to 
discard records if I have no check-out within X-hours or if I find a check-out without 
a check-in.

I have been trying with pandas and it looked so prommissing but as a new-be 
I got stuck on all the huge possiblities that this magical package offers. 
I hope some one can help me out and maybe can explane me a little bit where 
to look fore.

Many thanks in advance,

avm

Comment: requirement clarification is needed:- what is algo to find a check-out without a check-in. Also share what you have tried thus far.

Comment: To be honest, not much. I have been stumbling around to get to this minimal data-set as the record where actually comming from differrent sources (I build the Id from other information, probably not the best way. If I would programm it, I would count A's and for every B I would substract by one. Negative numbers of A are then not allowed and that B-record would be discarded. Therefore, I asked for a X-hours rule so I can play a bit with it, every time I disregard a A record, I might have afterwards a B-record that I have to disregard.

Comment: check this schenarion: A checked in @ 07:45 AM, A checked in @ 07:50 AM, A checked out @ 09:15 AM - here can you tell which A (1st check in or 2nd check in) has checked out?

Comment: We would always take the longest outstanding check-in if a check-out is found. So in your case, the 07:45 check-in would be "coupled" with a check-out.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is not structured in such a way that you can do this with one query. If you had a check_in_id column  which would be and added column then you could do it with one  query. the idea being that there would be at most two rows with the same check_in_id and they would always have the same id.

So instead write a stored procedure to create a tmp table. The  tmp table would contain the added column. Your stored procedure would need iterate over the rows of the table and find the most recent check out given the id, that is not already in the tmp table.